# Is it possible to use newlines in `xxx` in a fold marker `xxx {{{`?

Tags: folding

In my source code, I have this fold marker:

```rust
// abc {{{
println!("Hello, world!");
//}}}
```

And this is displayed as one line:

```
+--  3 lines: abc
```

But is it possible to use a newline in `abc` above?

The result I want is

```
+-- 63 lines:
  binary_search(left, right, f(T) -> Ordering),
  lower_bound(left, right, f(T) -> bool),
  upper_bound(left, right, f(T) -> bool)
```

rather than one long line:

```
+-- 63 lines: binary_search(left, right, f(T) -> Ordering), lower_bound(left, right, f(T) -> bool), upper_bound(left, right, f(T) -> bool)
```

Comment: To me, your example could be clearer. Could you give us the code for the second example?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Just as `// abc {{{`, the code is `// binary_search(left, right, f(T) -> Ordering), lower_bound(left, right, f(T) -> bool), upper_bound(left, right, f(T) -> bool) {{{`.

Answer (score 3):

No, what you want is not possible. A closed fold is displayed as one single line  and there is nothing you can do about it.

The little leeway you have with how closed folds look is:

- the text that is displayed in the fold line, limited to a single line, via `:help 'foldtext'`,
- the character used for filling up the line, via `:help 'fillchars'`,
- the styling, via `:help hl-folded`.